# how can i make this js code to python it's generate some kind of string and number

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can i do this code with python
it's generate some kind of string and numbre
for example `5ee8ead009f86895`

```
    a(16)
    function a(t) {
            function e() {
                return n ? 15 & n[r++] : 16 * Math.random() | 0
            }
            var n = null
                , r = 0
                , o = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;
            o && o.getRandomValues && Uint8Array && (n = o.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(t)));
            for (var i = [], a = 0; a < t; a++)
                i.push(e().toString(16));
            return i.join("")
        }
```

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood that Stack Overflow is a free online code translation service. It is not. Please read [ask] and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: This looks like it is creating a hex token which can be done with a buit-in Python library https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_hex. E.g. `secrets.token_hex(8)` gives a value that looks like: `5ee8ead009f86895`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand properly you want to write code in Python that can generate random tokens
This is written in Python3

```
import random as rd

def myToken(num):
    #num is the length of tokens
    myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,"a","b","c","d","e","f"]
    #you can add more characters to the list above
    myStr = ""
    randChars = (rd.choices(myList, weights=None,cum_weights=None,k=num))
    for i in randChars:
        myStr += str(i)
    print(myStr)
    return myStr

myToken(16)
```

Comment: For security tokens Python's [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) library should be used in preference to the default pseudo-random number generator in the random module, which is designed for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography. The above could be done as a one liner with `''.join([secrets.choice(string.hexdigits[:-6]) for x in range(16)])`